# Creating json objects that consit of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

In laravel I am getting list of articles from my query and later I am getting foreach of these articles number of comments and paths for all of their image files and videos. My goal is to make an array of json objects that would look like this:

```
[{
   id: id,
   title: title,
   summary: summary,
   comments: 'commentsCount',
   images: {
      path: 'path',
      path: 'path',
      path: 'path',
    }
 },
...
]
```

Not sure how to combine and make that kind of an array, this is my failed attempt:

```
$result = Article::where('publish', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);
    $articles = [];

    foreach($result as $article){
      $articles[] = $article;
      $articles[]['comments'] = $article->comments()->count();

      foreach ($article->medias as $media){
        $articles[]['comments']['images'] = $media->path;
      }
    }
```

Updated code:

This is was the simplest solution that gave me wanted result:

```
$result = Article::where('publish', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);

    foreach($result as $article){
      $articles[$article->id] = $article;
      $articles[$article->id]['comments'] = $article->comments()->count();
      $articles[$article->id]['medias'] = $article->medias()->get();
    }

    return $articles;
```

Comment: That JSON is impossible. You need something like either `images: [{ path: 'path' }, { path: 'path' }, { path: 'path' }]` (an array of objects, useful if your images have more data than just a path, like an ID or caption) or `images: ['path', 'path', 'path']` (an array of simple strings).

Comment: As for building out the array, `$articles[]['comments']['images'][] = $media->path;` should do the trick.

Comment: @ceejayoz I am sorry my example was written badly, but something like what you suggested would be good, I just struggle to achieve that

Comment: @ceejayoz $articles[]['comments']['images'][] = $media->path; is not doing a trick, since it is giving me results like this:  {"comments":{"images":["files\/uploads\/articles\/33\/coop-prix-logo-facebook.png"]}},{"comments":{"images":["files\/uploads\/articles\/33\/download-1.jpeg"]}},{"comments":{"images":["files\/uploads\/articles\/33\/download-2.jpeg"]}},{"comments":{"images":["files\/uploads\/articles\/33\/download-4.jpeg"]}},{"comments":{"images":["files\/uploads\/articles\/33\/download-3.jpeg"]}},{"comments":{"images":["files\/uploads\/articles\/33\/download-5.jpeg"]}},

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is the way you use `[]`:

```
foreach($result as $article){
  $articles[] = $article;
  $articles[]['comments'] = $article->comments()->count();

  foreach ($article->medias as $media){
    $articles[]['comments']['images'] = $media->path;
  }
}
```

Every time you write `$articles[] ... = ...` you append a brand new element to the end of the array.

If you want to append one element and then append subelements you need a different approach:

1. Specify an index inside the brackets (which you can be a variable).
2. Compose the element first into a temporary variable, append it once at the end of the loop iteration.